Books and lecture notes about Moduli spaces of Abelian varieties
Following this question, I would like to ask about books and lecture notes for Moduli spaces of Abelian varieties. I suppose that Mumfords book "Geometric Invariant theory" treats it but it is a very dense and difficult book for a first study.

Birkenhake--Lange has a lot of material on this topic, in the complex setting.

Do you mean their chapter "Moduli Spaces of Abelian Varieties with Endomorphism Structure" in " Complex Abelian Varieties "? Is it an introductory one?

In my copy (2nd ed.) Chapter 8 is titled "Moduli" and Chapter 9 is the one you mention.

There are also these notes by K. Buzzard: https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/moduli_spaces_for_abelian_varieties_over_C.pdf

Besides the chapter on Moduli in the classical textbook by Birkenhake-Lange, you might have a look at
A. Adler - S. Ramanan: Moduli of Abelian varieties, Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1644, Springer 1996.
